# How to simulate joint friction in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic, friction

I sucessfully created a custom effort controller for my robot but I'm having an issue related to joint friction. I load the robot in gazebo and just compesate gravity, so the robot is still in the initial position. When I apply a torque in the axis 1 in z direction the robot turns but doesnt stop, seems that friction is inexistent.

I gave friction values to my joints in the urdf so, I 100% sure I'm missing something but i dont know what. This is my urdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
  <xacro:include filename="$(find staubli_tx90_support)/urdf/common_materials.xacro"/>

  <xacro:macro name="staubli_tx90" params="prefix">
    <!-- links: main serial chain -->
    <link name="${prefix}base_link">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/visual/base_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <xacro:material_staubli_ral_melon_yellow />
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/collision/base_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
          <mass value="10.733459"/>
          <origin xyz="0.014288 0.000001 0.122264" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
          <inertia ixx="0.096590" ixy="-0.000005" ixz="-0.003803"
                                  iyy="0.087591"  iyz="-0.000001"
                                                  izz="0.081632"/>
       
      </inertial>
      <gazebo reference="${prefix}base_link">
        <mu1>0.2</mu1>
        <mu2>0.2</mu2>
      </gazebo>
      
    </link>
    <link name="${prefix}link_1">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/visual/link_1.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <xacro:material_staubli_ral_melon_yellow />
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/collision/link_1.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
          <mass value="16.934564"/>
          <origin xyz="0.019143 0.024764 -0.064596" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
          <inertia ixx="0.222318" ixy="0.016499" ixz="0.023794"
                                  iyy="0.208959" iyz="0.031663"
                                                 izz="0.157081"/>
      
      </inertial>
      <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_1">
        <mu1>0.2</mu1>
        <mu2>0.2</mu2>
      </gazebo>
      
    </link>
    <link name="${prefix}link_2">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/visual/link_2.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <xacro:material_staubli_ral_melon_yellow />
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/collision/link_2.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
          <mass value="12.98711"/>
          <origin xyz="-0.000008 0.221181 0.173052" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
          <inertia ixx="0.425299" ixy="0.000005" ixz="-0.000004"
                                  iyy="0.452311" iyz="-0.002920"
                                                 izz="0.054493"/>
      
      </inertial>
      <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_2">
        <mu1>0.2</mu1>
        <mu2>0.2</mu2>
      </gazebo>
      
    </link>
    <link name="${prefix}link_3">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/visual/link_3.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <xacro:material_staubli_ral_melon_yellow />
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/collision/link_3.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
          <mass value="7.50151"/>
          <origin xyz="0.000002 0.065008 0.003572" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
          <inertia ixx="0.058902" ixy="0.000000" ixz="0.000001"
                                  iyy="0.056884" iyz="-0.003672"
                                                 izz="0.034271"/>
      
      </inertial>
      <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_3">
        <mu1>0.2</mu1>
        <mu2>0.2</mu2>
      </gazebo>
      
      
    </link>
    <link name="${prefix}link_4">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/visual/link_4.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <xacro:material_staubli_ral_melon_yellow />
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/collision/link_4.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
          <mass value="4.54015"/>
          <origin xyz="-0.002488 0.049988 0.296156" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
          <inertia ixx="0.043246" ixy="0.000003" ixz="-0.000683"
                                  iyy="0.038394" iyz="-0.000004"
                                                 izz="0.014525"/>
      
      </inertial>
      <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_4">
        <mu1>0.2</mu1>
        <mu2>0.2</mu2>
      </gazebo>
      
    </link>
    <link name="${prefix}link_5">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/visual/link_5.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <xacro:material_staubli_ral_grey_aluminium />
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/collision/link_5.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
          <mass value="0.56876"/>
          <origin xyz="0.000000 0.049931 0.222823" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
          <inertia ixx="0.001084" ixy="0.000000" ixz="0.000000"
                                  iyy="0.001123" iyz="0.000001"
                                                 izz="0.000383"/>
      
      </inertial>
      <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_5">
        <mu1>0.2</mu1>
        <mu2>0.2</mu2>
      </gazebo>
    </link>
    <link name="${prefix}link_6">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/visual/link_6.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <xacro:material_staubli_ral_grey_aluminium />
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://staubli_tx90_support/meshes/tx90/collision/link_6.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
          <mass value="0.03098"/>
          <origin xyz="-0.000243 0.050000 -0.006293" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
          <inertia ixx="0.000012" ixy="0.000000" ixz="0.000000"
                                  iyy="0.000011" iyz="0.000000"
                                                 izz="0.000022"/>
      </inertial>
      <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_1">
        <mu1>0.2</mu1>
        <mu2>0.2</mu2>
      </gazebo>
    </link>

    <!-- joints: main serial chain -->
    <joint name="${prefix}joint_1" type="revolute">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.478" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${prefix}base_link"/>
      <child link="${prefix}link_1"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <!-- from Staubli instruction manual:
      (1) effort limit = 318 Nm if floor mounted
      (2) effort limit = 111 Nm if wall mounted -->
      <limit lower="${radians(-180)}" upper="${radians(180)}" effort="318.0" velocity="${radians(400)}" />
      <dynamics damping="0.003" friction="0.0" mu_viscous="68"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="${prefix}joint_2" type="revolute">
      <origin xyz="0.050 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${prefix}link_1"/>
      <child link="${prefix}link_2"/>
      <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
      <limit lower="${radians(-130)}" upper="${radians(147.5)}" effort="166.0" velocity="${radians(400)}" />
      <dynamics damping="0.003" friction="0.0" mu_viscous="72"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="${prefix}joint_3" type="revolute">
      <origin xyz="0 0.05 0.425" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${prefix}link_2"/>
      <child link="${prefix}link_3"/>
      <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
      <limit lower="${radians(-145)}" upper="${radians(145)}" effort="76.0" velocity="${radians(430)}" />
      <dynamics damping="0.003" friction="0.0" mu_viscous="15"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="${prefix}joint_4" type="revolute">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${prefix}link_3"/>
      <child link="${prefix}link_4"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <limit lower="${radians(-270)}" upper="${radians(270)}" effort="34.0" velocity="${radians(540)}" />
      <dynamics damping="0.003" friction="0.0" mu_viscous="10"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="${prefix}joint_5" type="revolute">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.425" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${prefix}link_4"/>
      <child link="${prefix}link_5"/>
      <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
      <limit lower="${radians(-115)}" upper="${radians(140)}" effort="29.0" velocity="${radians(475)}" />
      <dynamics damping="0.003" friction="0.0" mu_viscous="7"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="${prefix}joint_6" type="revolute">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.100" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${prefix}link_5"/>
      <child link="${prefix}link_6"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <limit lower="${radians(-270)}" upper="${radians(270)}" effort="11.0" velocity="${radians(760)}" />
      <dynamics damping="0.003" friction="0.0" mu_viscous="3.5"/>
    </joint>

    <!-- ROS-Industrial 'base' frame: base_link to Staubli World Coordinates transform -->
    <link name="${prefix}base" />
    <joint name="${prefix}base_link-base" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.478" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${prefix}base_link"/>
      <child link="${prefix}base"/>
    </joint>

    <!-- ROS-Industrial 'flange' frame: attachment point for EEF models -->
    <link name="${prefix}flange" />
    <joint name="${prefix}joint_6-flange" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 ${radians(-90.0)} 0" />
      <parent link="${prefix}link_6" />
      <child link="${prefix}flange" />
    </joint>

    <!-- ROS-Industrial 'tool0' frame: all-zeros tool frame -->
    <link name="${prefix}tool0" />
    <joint name="${prefix}flange-tool0" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 ${radians(90.0)} 0" />
      <parent link="${prefix}flange" />
      <child link="${prefix}tool0" />
    </joint>

  </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

Comment: Have you tried bumping up the friction and damping coefficients?

Comment: yep and there is no change in the simulation... I added this to the urdf just to try but no way.  <gazebo reference="${prefix}">
      <dynamics damping="0.01" friction="0.02"/>
    </gazebo>

Comment: Remove mu_viscous, maybe your gazebo version does not support such parameter and fails to load the dynamics tag